# Wordpress Menu Issue

Tags: php, wordpress

Can someone help me with my Wordpress menu for a custom plugin I'm creating?

```
        // Add the menu, only for administrators            
        public function add_menu(){
            if(is_admin()){
                add_menu_page(__('EM Collaboration Main Page', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                  __('EM Collaboration', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                  'manage_options', 
                                  'em-collaboration/em-main.php', 
                                  '', '', 21);
                add_submenu_page('em-collaboration/em-main.php', 
                                      __('EM Collaboration Main Page', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                      __('All Collab Groups', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                      'manage_options', 
                                      'em-collaboration/em-main.php');
            }
        }
```

The sub-menu is not showing for some reason, and I am really unsure as to why that is...
I've looked through the codex and from what I can see it should be showing...

## UPDATE

```
        // Add the menu, only for administrators            
        public function add_menu(){
            if(is_admin()){
                add_menu_page(__('EM Collaboration All Groups', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                  __('EM Collaboration', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                  'manage_options',
                                  'em-collab-top', 
                                  'em-collaboration/em-main.php', 
                                  '', 
                                  21);
                add_submenu_page('em-collab-top', 
                                      __('EM Collaboration Settings', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                      __('Settings', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                      'manage_options', 
                                      'em-collaboration/em-settings.php');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the menu_slug. It is the parameter behind 'manage_options'. You chose 'em-collaboration/em-main.php' for the menu and the submenu. The reference says, if both are the same the menu point won't be duplicated.

[add_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)

So your code has to look same like:

```
public function add_menu(){
        if(is_admin()){
            add_menu_page(__('EM Collaboration Main Page', 'em-collaboration'), 
                              __('EM Collaboration', 'em-collaboration'), 
                              'manage_options', 
                              '<the_menu_slug>', 
                              '', '', 21);
            add_submenu_page('em-collaboration/em-main.php', 
                                  __('EM Collaboration Main Page', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                  __('All Collab Groups', 'em-collaboration'), 
                                  'manage_options', 
                                  '<the_submenu_slug>');
        }
    }
```

"the_menu_slug" and "the_submenu_slug" need to differ to show a submenu. This slugs don't need to be a name of the file. It is just an alias name for the menu entry.

Comment: This seems to do it (updated code in the question), but how can I change the inner EM Collaboration title, to something like 'All Groups'

Comment: or... how can I prevent the top level item from showing in the sub-menu, and prevent it from acutally linking to anything...